# Unity3d Raycast on mesh position

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, coordinates, mesh

I want to hit a mesh with a raycast and get the mouse/screen coordinates of where the hit occurred.

```
public class GetCoordinates: MonoBehaviour {

    private GameObject _objectToHit;

    private RaycastHit hit;
    private Collider coll;
    private Ray ray;
    private float hitDistance = 200f;

    void Start()
    {
        coll = GetComponent<Collider>();
        _objectToHit = GameObject.Find("Street");
    }

    void Update()
    {
        ray = Camera.main.ScreenPointToRay(Input.mousePosition);

        if (coll.Raycast(ray, out hit, hitDistance))
        {
              Debug.Log(hit.point);
        }
    }
}
```

Also I am not sure where to add the script, to the object being hit or to the camera?

Comment: I don't know where you got that script but it looks alright, why haven't you tried adding it to the object or the camera? (I know which one you should add it to, but I think you should try to figure it out for yourself, considering you already have the script)

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because this calls for an EXTREMELY BASIC TUTORIAL IN THE SUBJECT (note for example "I don't know where to put the script"), rather than an actual question-answer. There is no "answer" here other than a long tutorial.

Comment: it's possible you're looking for `RAYCASTALL`. You can very easily find a HUGE number of QA and tutorials on this.

Comment: hi @silentace, are you there?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You want to use [Camera.WorldToScreenPoint](http://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Camera.WorldToScreenPoint.html) to convert the world hit point position into screen position.
Also you need to have only one instance of this script in your game otherwise you'll have several ray casts. You should consider this before choosing where to put this script. We can not help you to make this choice without more informations on what it is used for, on how many objects, etc.

EDIT about the script use:

One thing is certain: the ray cast script has to have a unique instance. If you want to interact with other objects through this script, you should use the [GameObject.GetComponent](http://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/GameObject.GetComponent.html) function on hit.collider.gameobject in order to access the script that will do the what you want.

For example, if you have a gate on your street, clicking on it will call the toggleOpen() function contained in the GateBehaviour script on the Gate object like that :

```
if (coll.Raycast(ray, out hit, hitDistance))
{
    if(hit.collider.tag == "Gate")
    {
        GateBehaviour gate = hit.collider.gameobject.GetComponent<GateBehaviour>()
        if(gate)
            gate.toggleOpen();
    }
    Debug.Log(hit.point);
}
```

You should ideally have something like a class called Interractable that would offer a unique interface for all the interractable objects on the street. The street itself could also inherit from this interface.

Comment: I have multiple objects to hit with a raycast, and get their positions of hit. It would be most efficient to have only script attached to the camera. But i need to also highlight those objects as well, so i am not quite sure where to add the script. What happens if i have 30 game objects. Do i individually add the script to all of them?

Comment: Could you describe what you want to do? If you want to display an fx on hit, you can have only one script on the camera. If you want to do something on the object on hit (applying a force on it for example), you will need to write another script and attach it to each object.

Comment: I have a street mesh which should be a spawn point. The click position doesn't really matter as long as it's on the street. Also there are multiple objects on the street, like cubes, orbs etc. The most important things is the position being clicked on the street, as well as the same script should also highlight the other objects when i hover my mouse over them. I plan to add other interactions with the objects later on, which is still the same thing get their hit position, only on that object.

Comment: Typing fast and looking at scripts. My bad. The coordinates are important when you click on the street for the spawn point.

Comment: hi @stud while your answer admirably explains one concept, really you should just vote to close this question.  the question now includes at least 7 totally separate questions (all of which are incredibly easily searched).  OP this site WELCOMES your QUESTIONS, but they have to be actual questions with one answer.  You can find awesome beginner tutorials for this sort of thing